# How to have a (physical) light with the status of the continuous build?

Tags: continuous-integration, hardware

Having this would be great: a light (a LED, or even just a bulb) that is green/yellow/red depending on the status of *the build*. If the latest build of your continuous integration failed because of a compile error, it shows red; if the reason was a failed test it's yellow; otherwise is green and everyone is happy.

So, this light needs to be connected to a computer, which checks the status of your solution for continuous integration (Atlassian's Bamboo in my case, but you name it), and chooses the color. Now that makes for great (and geeky) office decoration!

Any ideas on how to put in place such a system in a reasonable time/price frame?

Comment: You can buy USB systems to provide visual and or audio feedback for various status conditions. Not really a programming question, so I'm voting to migrate to Super User. My downvote is because *"I know it's off topic, but I want this audience"* does *not* fly.

Comment: I had a look at superuser and saw most of the questions were software oriented anyway, while I did find some questions about electronics and hardware here. It's not programming, but who else other than a programmer would want such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Misuse LEDs in the wanted colors and an old computer with a parallel port for it. Then set ports on the parallel port to on/off using [Parapin](http://parapin.sourceforge.net/). The hardware part is as easy as pushing the cables in the ports.

Actually, I already did that myself, just stuffed the LED into the parallel port and it worked.